# how to related value and function without OO

Tags: c++, design-patterns, node.js, v8

My function `init` return an `v8::Handle<Object>`, and this `Object` contains several `Handle<Function>` properties e.g. `bar`.

```
var foo = require('foo').init({a:'a', b:'b'});
foo.bar('a');
```

In my addon code:

```
Handle<Object> Bar (Arguments &args) {
  // !! how to access mystruct* p for current call?
}

Handle<Object> Init(Arguments &args) {
  HandleScope scope;
  mystruct* p = InitMyStructWithArgs(args);
  Object ret;
  // !! how to bind mystruct* p to Bar?
  NODE_SET_METHOD(ret, 'bar', Bar);
  scope.Close(ret);
}
```

You see that, Bar, Obj, args all standalone, there is no relative between them, so I can't get `mystruct*` which init by `{a:'a', b:'b'}` in the `Bar`

Comment: It's kind of tough to follow what you are asking. Could you elaborate a bit more?

Answer (score 2):

### Example

You need to bind your custom c++ objects via `SetPointerInInternalField` to your returned objects.

Then you can access your c++ objects via `GetPointerFromInternalField` from your object functions.

C++

```
#include <v8.h>
#include <node.h>

using namespace v8;
using namespace node;

namespace {

struct Sample {
  int counter;
};

Handle<Value> Add(const Arguments& args) {
  HandleScope scope;

  Sample *sample = static_cast<Sample*>(args.This()->GetPointerFromInternalField(0));

  return scope.Close(Number::New(sample->counter));
}

Handle<Value> Init(const Arguments& args) {
  HandleScope scope;

  Sample* sample = new Sample();
  sample->counter = 5;

  Local<ObjectTemplate> objectTemplate = ObjectTemplate::New();
  objectTemplate->SetInternalFieldCount(1);

  Local<Object> ret = objectTemplate->NewInstance();

  ret->SetPointerInInternalField(0, sample);
  ret->Set(String::New("add"), FunctionTemplate::New(Add)->GetFunction());

  return scope.Close(ret);
}

extern "C" void init(Handle<Object> target) {
  HandleScope scope;

  target->Set(String::New("init"), FunctionTemplate::New(Init)->GetFunction());
}

} // anonymous namespace
```

JavaScript

```
var foo = test.init();
console.log(foo.add());  // 5
```

Reference

http://izs.me/v8-docs/classv8_1_1ObjectTemplate.html

Comment: How would you handle deallocation of the Sample object created? Adding a destructor to the Sample struct and logging something to the output reveals that deallocation does not take place with your sample code (at least not with node.js 0.10.26)